# Logarithmic Equation: Solve for $x$

Tags: logarithms

$$\log_{3x}81 = 2$$
How would I go about solving this? This is what I tried:

$$\log_{3x}81 = 2$$

$$\frac{\log81}{\log 3 + \log x }= 2$$

Where do I go from here?

If I isolate $\log x$ on one side, how do I get rid of the log?

Comment: $81=3^4$, so $\log81=4\log3$.

Comment: Or, do $(3x)^\textrm{both sides}$ from the start.

Comment: Do you mind showing me your steps for this? Are you starting at where I left off?

Comment: The second thing is starting from the start. Remember that $(3x)^{\log_{3x}(\textrm{stuff})}=\textrm{stuff}$.

Comment: Aside from the simple way of doing this that others have already posted, you can also solve the equation $\dfrac{\log81}{\log 3 + \log x }= 2$ for $x$.  I explained how in an answer posted below. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\log_{3x}(81)=2$ is equivalent to

$$(3x)^2=9x^2=81$$

by the definition of the logarithm.

$$9x^2=81 \Leftrightarrow x^2=9$$

This gives solutions $x=3$ and $x=-3$, but only $x=3$ is a solution, since the base of a logarithm must be greater than zero.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. For some reason I failed to see that I could isolate x very easily once I "booted the log".

Answer (score 4):

For any two real numbers $b$ and $x$ where $b$ is positive and $b ≠ 1$,

$$  y=b^z\Leftrightarrow z=\log_b(y) $$
so for $\log_{3x}81=2$ we have
$$
(3x)^2=81=(3\cdot 3)^2\Rightarrow x=3
$$

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the simpler way of solving this that someone else has already posted, here's something else you can do:
$$
\frac{\log81}{\log 3 + \log x }= 2
$$
$$
\frac{\log 3 + \log x}{\log 81} = \frac 1 2
$$
$$
\log 3 + \log x = \frac 1 2 \log 81
$$
$$
\log x = \frac 1 2 \log 81 - \log 3 = \frac 1 2 \log(3^4) - \log 3
$$
$$
=\frac 1 2\cdot 4 \log 3 - \log 3 = \left(\frac 1 2\cdot 4 - 1\right)\log 3 = \log 3.
$$
Now you have
$$
\log x = \log 3,
$$
and since logarithmic functions are one-to-one, you can conclude that $x=3$.

Comment: Thank-you, that is very helpful.